# Php ranking system and get the average of all duplicate rank

Tags: php, arrays, ranking

I have this application that will automatically rank the candidates based on their score.

```
[
    {"candidate":"12","rank":1},
    {"candidate":"11","rank":2},
    {"candidate":"10","rank":3},
    {"candidate":"9","rank":4},
    {"candidate":"8","rank":4},
    {"candidate":"7","rank":6},
    {"candidate":"6","rank":7},
    {"candidate":"5","rank":8},
    {"candidate":"4","rank":9},
    {"candidate":"3","rank":9},
    {"candidate":"2","rank":11},
    {"candidate":"1","rank":12}
]
```

Now, as you can see, candidates 4 and 9 got the same rank:

```
{"candidate":"9","rank":4}, // this supposed to rank 4
{"candidate":"8","rank":4}, // this supposed to rank 5
{"candidate":"4","rank":9}, // this supposed to rank 9
{"candidate":"3","rank":9}, // this supposed to rank 10
```

Calculation:
(first duplicate)

```
4 + 5 = 9
9 / 2 (number of duplicate rank) = 4.5
```

(second duplicate)

```
9 + 9 = 18
18 / 2(number of duplicate rank) = 9
```

**EDIT - shouldn't this be**

```
9 + 10 = 19
19 / 2(number of duplicate rank) = 9.5
```

Expected Output:

```
  [
        {"candidate":"12","rank":1},
        {"candidate":"11","rank":2},
        {"candidate":"10","rank":3},
        {"candidate":"9","rank":4.5},
        {"candidate":"8","rank":4.5},
        {"candidate":"7","rank":6},
        {"candidate":"6","rank":7},
        {"candidate":"5","rank":8},
        {"candidate":"4","rank":9.5},
        {"candidate":"3","rank":9.5},
        {"candidate":"2","rank":11},
        {"candidate":"1","rank":12}
    ]
```

Note: This is just a simple scenario and ranking will change anytime.

Comment: You need to show us a complete example including your code. For example, how are you assigning the values after calculating the average?

Comment: that's my question on how to be in expected output

Comment: _"Now, as you can see. rank 4 and 9 are duplicate"_ - and? That is a very common thing in rankings - so where is the problem with that? I don't really see much sense in converting this to a "rank" of 4.5, considering that a rank is usually understood to be an integer.